# How to use previous tile rendering system with blender 3.0?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

Blender 3.0 is insanely slow for me on cpu. Its fast in the viewport but the rendertimes are 2-3x slower than 2.93. I really want to use the geometry nodes and other improvement s in 3.0. Is there a way to use the 2.93 tile rendering system with 3.0? I really dont want to have to work on an outdated version of blender until this thing gets fixed.

Specs:

Cpu: intel i7 4790k
Gpu: No gpu
Ram: 16gb ddr3 1600mhz

Comment: Maybe you can share a File where you encounter this problem. https://blend-exchange.com/

Answer (score 4):

Go in the `Properties Editor` > `Render` tab > `Performance` panel > `Memory` subpanel. You can set the tile size here. It's at 2048 by default.

[image: render settings]

Answer (score 4):

Tiled Rendering will be slower in almost all cases than the new Systems.
Your problem most likesly comes from another Source.

With [CyclesX](https://code.blender.org/2021/04/cycles-x/) there are [improved algorithms](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/render_settings/sampling.html#adaptive-sampling) that decide automaticly and more fine grain where to render how mutch, and dont waste render time on already converged areas. This allows for a more [user centered approach](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/3.0/Cycles#Sampling) letting you decide in genereal how noisy of an image or how mutch rendertime is okay for you - instead of fiddeling with numbers and see wat comes out and retry if it wasn't okay.