# Blender 3 - What the heck happened to Hilbert Spiral?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, tilesize

I've been using Blender since 2.79, and I'm very used to rendering with the Hilbert Spiral tiling mode, which renders tiles from the center and spreads outward. This makes sense to me, since it lets you confirm that the important part of the render (usually in the center) is correct, and if not, you can cancel sooner rather than later.

I've since updated to Blender 3.0.0. **Where the heck did this Hilbert Spiral option go?**

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/245158/multi-tile-rendering-in-cycles-x https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/244994/no-auto-tile-size-in-blender-3-0 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/244907/how-to-use-previous-tile-rendering-system-with-blender-3-0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the big update of Cycles render engine ([dubbed Cycles-X](https://code.blender.org/2021/04/cycles-x/)) in Blender 3.0, tiles have been removed due to substantial architectural changes. They will be back *"to support high res renders, but in a different form. All devices and CPU cores will likely be cooperating on the same tile. —brecht (principle developer of Cycles)"* When that'll happen is not known yet.

Comment: And overall, the tiles do not serve the same purpose anymore. So right now, most people probably shouldn't even use them at all.

Answer (score 1):

Instead, define a *Render Region* with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> while looking through the camera in *Object Mode*.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> clears the region, but honestly I just use a region the full size of the camera to stop the render preview from rendering pixels outside of the camera frame.  Saves some time.

Comment: Thanks! I couldn't remember the shortcut for that trick. I may have also been in edit mode too, which didn't help.

Comment: Be careful, ctrl b in edit mode is bevel :)